# Loging out issue in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, logout, tabbarcontroller

I have created an tabbar based iphone app, for the login page i used the following method:

```
@protocol LoginViewControllerDelegate;
@interface TradeBarcodeViewController: UIViewController{
id<LoginViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}
@protocol LoginViewControllerDelegate
-(void)loginViewControllerDidFinish:(TradeBarcodeViewController *)loginViewController;
@end

@implementation TradeBarcodeViewController

[self.delegate loginViewControllerDidFinish:self];
@end
```

It is working fine and I can loggin to the tabbar controled app. In one of the tabbar viewconroller there is a button for Logout. I used the following for that:

```
TradeBarcodeViewController *vc = [[TradeBarcodeViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentModalViewController:vc
                            animated:NO];
    [vc release];
```

Then it will again navigate to the login page, but if I try to login again it is not working. What went wrong here? Or which method should I use to logout from my app?
Thanks.

Comment: use in logout action [self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: I tried, but the app crashing, and the log in window is not one of the viewcontrollers of tabbar controller.

Comment: Since, the logout button is in one of the Tabbar conrtoller, I used [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; Now the app is not crashing and no warning. But nothing is happening.

Comment: I calling a web service and depending upon the result i'm loging in. And I used the code as in my post for logging.

Comment: do u push ur login page..like [self.navigationController pushViewController:abc animated:YES];

Comment: no, it is not working because the log in page is not in the tabbar controller.

Answer (score 0):

if your login page is not in tabbar then when u click logout use this code

//here u need to clear the field from database which checks for username and password 
[tabBar.view removeFromSuperview];

[tabBar release];

tabBar = nil;

[self addLoginPage];

Then in addLoginPage function add this

LoginPageViewController *loginView = [[LoginPageViewController alloc] init];

```
navigation=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginView];


[window addSubview:navigation.view];
```